# Passing specific data to webworkers

Tags: web-worker

I have a WebWorker counting up for me, but I want to be able to tell it to subtract by a specific amount (as single action, i.e once) whenever I want.

Current code:

```
var i = 0;

    function incrementMoney() {
      i = i + 1;
      postMessage(i);
      setTimeout("incrementMoney()",1000);
    }

incrementMoney();
```

Comment: Explain further what you want. Add example spinet with the code you already have. The snippet must be working. After you do that, please reply to my comment and I will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sth like this:

```
// worker script
var x = 0, dx = 1, current_action='add';
var actions = {
'add': function( ) { x += dx; },
'subtract': function( ) { x -= dx; }
};

onmessage = function( evt ) {
   if ( evt.data && evt.data.action && evt.data.action in actions)
   {
     if ( true === evt.data.once )
     {
         // store current state
         var prev_action = current_action, prev_dx = dx;
         current_action = evt.data.action;
         if ( null != evt.data.amount ) dx = evt.data.amount;
         // do action once,
         // optionaly, you can also stop the "doAction timer"
         // and restart it after finishing this action, ie below
         // but left it as is for now
         actions[current_action]( );
         // restore state
         current_action = prev_action;
         dx = prev_dx;
     }
     else
     {
         current_action = evt.data.action;
         if ( null != evt.data.amount ) dx = evt.data.amount;
     }
   }
};

function doAction( )
{
   actions[current_action]( );
   postMessage( x );   
   setTimeout(doAction,1000);
}

doAction( );
```

Then whenever you need you send a message to your worker with an `action` parameter to either `add` or `subtract` (you can add other custom actions if needed and use "action messages" to get worker to do the action)

```
// main script
myworker.postMessage({action:'subtract', amount:5, once:true});
```

Comment: I don't need to be able to add to it. All I need to be able to do is to tell it to subtract by `currentCost[n]`

Comment: JOk. Ignore my edited comment back there.  What does dx do? Also, you forgot braces up there in the evt.data.amount if statement, too.

Comment: `dx` is the amount of increment/decrement, so just pass `myworker.postMessage({action:'subtract', amount:currentCost[n]});`

Comment: I have a new problem: I pass it a "subtract 10", but then it simply starts counting down by tens instead of subtracting 10 one time. (Also you forgot braces in an if statement up there, too.)

Comment: ok, your question is not clear about how you want to subtract, so added similar to increment, updating answer

Comment: My goal is something like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, (subtract 3 passed here) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc

Comment: ok updated answer, if you need you can also stop the timer while doing the once action and restart it after finishing, but left it for now